# Curl batch file

Tags: batch-file, curl

I have the following batch file that is executing cURL POST command:

```
curl -k -X POST -F "upload=@xxx0101.csv" -F "mail=******" -F "pwd=******" -F "orgid=2729" -F "response=JSON" https:************* >> log.txt
SET Today=%Date:~10,4%%Date:~4,2%%Date:~7,2%
mkdir %cd%\Backup-%Today%
move %cd%\*.csv %cd%\Backup-%Today%\
```

I would like the conditional execution of the latter part of the script(after the CURL has been executed) based on success/failure of the cURL POST command/file transfer.

Could you please help me with this.

Comment: Append `&&(` to the curl command and the closing parenthesis to the last line to be executed conditionally. And move the the `set Today` before the (code block) or you will need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: ...and remove the `%cd%` prefix as it points to the current directory anyway; it does not disturb until you follow @LotPings's advice (due to missing delayed expansion)...